# Clsedness of a sum of a subspace and a finite dimensional subspace in Hilbert spaces

Tags: hilbert-spaces

Let $K,L$ be subspaces of a Hilbert space $H$ such that $U=L+K$ and $K$ is finite dimensional. Can I justify that $U$ is colsed if and only if $L$ is closed?.

Thanks for your ideas.